# Not loading standard module Node.JS in webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, gulp, webpack

Problem with standart module NodeJS: url module, http, https, zlib,stream
my setting file:

```
webpack: {
        custom: {
            entry: './src/index.js',
            output: {
                path: 'build/',
                filename: 'index.js'
            },
            target: 'node',
            resolve: {
                extensions: [
                    '.js',
                ],
                root: '.'
            },
            module: {
                loaders: [
                    { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'jsx-loader' },
                ],

            }
        }
    }
```

After run build and open index.html, and see error in console: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
Opened details, and see:

```
function(module, exports) {

    module.exports = require("url");

},
```

Also and other standard default module Node.JS: http, https, zlib,stream

require not spun. How it fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change target 'node' to 'web' (`target: 'web'`).  And if using `require('fs')`, then necessery using transform loader with brfs: `{ test: /\.js$/, loader: 'transform?brfs!}`